# How to select table cells in a multi-row table header in their correct order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a thead like this:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">Cell-1</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Cell-2</th>        
     <th colspan="3">Header</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Cell-6</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th">Cell-3</th>
     <th">Cell-4</th>
     <th">Cell-5</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

I need to create a jquery selector with the cells in their correct order 1-2-3-4-5-6. Right now my selector looks like this:

```
hdrCols = thead.find( "tr:first th[rowspan=2], TR:first TH[rowspan=2]").add( thead.find( "tr:last-child th, TR:last-child TH" ) );
```

This gives me 1-2-6-3-4-5 and breaks my layout.

Is there a way to create a selector, which gets cells in their correct order? I cannot move the columns around, so any solution would have to encompass that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply using JavaScripts [sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6wYQt/

```
function sortHeaders(a, b) {
    var x = $(a).text().toLowerCase();
    var y = $(b).text().toLowerCase();

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
}

thead   = $('thead');
hdrCols = thead.find( "tr:first th[rowspan=2], TR:first TH[rowspan=2]").add( thead.find( "tr:last-child th, TR:last-child TH" ) );

hdrCols.sort(sortHeaders);

console.log(hdrCols);
​
```

Comment: Haha! Just beat me to the answer ;)

Comment: Nice! I added an attribute to my header cells, because cell content will not be cell-1, cell-2... Also works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to put the selected elements into an array, then write my own function to sort the array. So, step 1, get the elements and shove them into an array:

```
var elements = thread.find("th");
var elements_array = [];
elements.each(function(){
    elements_array.push($(this));
});
```

...then a custom function to attempt to sort them:

```
function custom_sort(a, b)
{
    // these elements are TH jQuery objects...
    var content_a = a.text();
    var content_b = b.text();

    // perform string comparison, for example...
    // return -1 if a comes before b, 1 if b comes before a, and
    // 0 if they're equal...
    return (a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0));
}

// finally sort the array of elements...
elements_array.sort(custom_sort);
```

That should do the trick, although I'm assuming the `TH` elements need to be sorted based on their contents, so that's why I implemented a string comparison in the sorting, although you could replace that with whatever you need! Hope this helps!

Comment: Haha no worries! I'll type faster next time...thanks for the upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this without adding attributes and having sortable column names, you could try this:

```
function extractTableHeader($table) {
    var $thead = $table.find('thead'),
        $row1 = $thead.children().first(),
        $children1 = $row1.children(),
        $row2 = $row1.next(),
        $children2 = $row2.children(),
        cells = [[],[]];

    // map first row
    $children1.each(function(){
        var $th = $(this),
            rows = $th.prop('rowspan'),
            cols = $th.prop('colspan'),
            _rows = rows > 1,
            _cols = cols > 1;

        while (cols) {
            cells[0].push(_cols ? null : this);

            if (!_rows) {
                cells[1].push(cells[0].length - 1);
            }
            cols--;
        }
    });

    $.each(cells[1], function(i, o){
        cells[0][o] = $children2[i];
    });

    return $(cells[0]);
}

$(function() {
    var $th = extractTableHeader($('table')),
        order = [];

    $th.each(function(){
        order.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(order.join(', '));
});

// output: Cell-1, Cell-2, Cell-3, Cell-4, Cell-5, Cell-6
```

Comment: also nice. but in my case it's more sorting cells regardless of th cell content. still +1